# gnome-shell remove shutdown/logout menu from gnome panel

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

How do i write a gnome extension in ubuntu 20.04 that removes the shutdown/logout menu seen in the screenshot with the red line......i cant find any documentation on it :?.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/Writing provides the useful information.

For a quick workaround to remove the Poweroff/Logout Menu in the Question, do the following steps..

run the below commands to create new extension ("remove_poweroff-logout_menu@username.domain") directory and required files. change what ever the name you want replacing "`remove_poweroff-logout_menu@username.domain`" in below command.

run

```
install -D /dev/null $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_poweroff-logout_menu@username.domain/extension.js
```

run

```
install -D /dev/null $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/remove_poweroff-logout_menu@username.domain/metadata.json
```

copy paste the below content in `extension.js` file

```
'use strict';

const Main = imports.ui.main;
const Menu = Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system.menu;

class Extension {
    constructor() {
    }

    enable() {
    Menu.actor.remove_child(Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system._sessionSubMenu);       
    }

    disable() {
    Menu.box.insert_child_at_index(Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system._sessionSubMenu, Main.panel.statusArea.aggregateMenu._system.menu.numMenuItems)
    }
}

function init() {
    return new Extension();
}
```

copy paste the below content in `metadata.json` file. Replace `remove_poweroff-logout_menu@username.domain` with the same name that you have created for the extenson's directory in below content. I have tested this extension in gnome-shell version 3.38, if you are testing different versions, you can edit shell-versions in below contents.

```
{
  "name": "Remove Poweroff/Logout Menu",
  "description": "Remove Poweroff/Logout Menu",
  "uuid": "remove_poweroff-logout_menu@username.domain",
  "shell-version": [
    "3.38"
  ]
}
```

Save the files & close..

If you are on Xorg session. you can refresh the gnome-shell with Alt+F2 r Enter method and then turn on the extension.

If you are on Wayland session. logout and login and then turn on the extension.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Many thanks  :), this works great :)